# A union of a conditions

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

i'm pretty new to prolog and now only the *very basics*
and i ran into a problem

i need to write a statement line this: `<cond.1> and (<cond.2> or <cond.3>)`

in languages like c++ it would look something like this:

```
if(<cond.1> && (<cond.2> || <cond.3>)) { /*...*/ }
```

And i tried this in prolog:

```
statement(X, Y, Z, W):-condition(X,Y,Z,W), !, X <> Z or Y <> W.
```

And this

```
statement(X, Y, Z, W):-condition(X,Y,Z,W) and (X <> Z or Y <> W).
```

And more things that google told me. Nothing worked, and i know that this logical statement would look like this in expanded form: `<cond.1> and <cond.2> or <cond.1> and <cond.3>`

But this is creates a frick ton of code and makes it unreadable. i just feel there has to be a way to implement these conditions inside a parentheses. But i just dont know how and i can't find any way to do it.

Comment: i found some info about this problem:
if i write something like this `cond(X, Y) :- (X = Y).`
it tell me about an error before equal sign  `406 ')' or ',' expected`
and this freak me out, bc how this kind of parentheses could not work?

Comment: The "or" would be a semicolon, so `;`, the "and" a comma `,`; and `X <> Z` is probably `X \= Z`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem nope. i tried this as well, only parentheses won't work for some reason

Comment: Try your problem in the online Prolog shell [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The "logical or" is denoted with a semicolon (`;`). So your predicate would likely look like:

```
statement(X, Y, Z, W) :-
    condition(X,Y,Z,W),
    (X \= Z; Y \= W).
```

Here the [**`\=/2`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%3D)/2) succeeds if it can not unify `X` with `Z` (or `Y` with `W`).

Comment: for `X \= Z` it says "illegal character". so with `X <> Z` it's working fine but still says 
`406 ')' or ',' expected` after X

Comment: @ZecosMAX: Then likely the error is located before the `statement` definition. For example you forgot a dot at the end of a clause, or a bracket, etc.

Comment: And not this.
well, i could just dump all of my code here (but i don't think that's a good tone)
i checked everything for 10 times. Everything should just work fine, but it does not. idk why.

Comment: Also my version of turbo prolog for some reason won't accept symbol '\'
So `true(X) :- \+ false(X).` won't work

Comment: @ZecosMAX: this looks really strange, since `\+` is a *ISO* Prolog predicate, so that means that everything that calls itself "standardized Prolog", should support that.

Comment: can you advice me an implementation of prolog (for dosbox maybe) which is for sure supports everything what prolog does?